# How do I manually validate a self-signed certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, validation, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I’ve been working a lot in Docker containers in the past couple of weeks and I came across the obstacle where a self signed cert was causing issues because the Docker container did not recognize the Certificate Authority.

The issue was that I was unable to put my own certs on the server configuration because the way we use Docker at my company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a good bit of research, I came up with a solution that manually validates the cert based off building the chain and verification of the thumbprint.

Note: You have to be using a library that supports a Certificate Validation Callback so that you can code your own delegate method. Below is my implementation.

```
public static bool ManualSslVerification(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    try
    {
        //Testing to see if the Certificate and Chain build properly, aka no forgery.
        chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        chain.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

        //Looking to see if there are no errors in the build that we don’t like
        foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
        {
            if (status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError || status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
            {
                //Acceptable Status, We want to know if it builds properly.
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        X509Certificate2 trustedRootCertificateAuthority = new X509Certificate2(ViewController.Properties.Resources.My_Infrastructure_Root_CA);

        //Now that we have tested to see if the cert builds properly, we now will check if the thumbprint of the root ca matches our trusted one
        if(chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count – 1].Certificate.Thumbprint != trustedRootCertificateAuthority.Thumbprint)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Once we have verified the thumbprint the last fun check we can do is to build the chain and then see if the remote cert builds properly with it
        //Testing to see if the Certificate and Chain build properly, aka no forgery.
        X509Chain trustedChain = new X509Chain();
        trustedChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(trustedRootCertificateAuthority);
        trustedChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;
        trustedChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        trustedChain.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

        //Looking to see if there are no errors in the build that we don’t like
        foreach (X509ChainStatus status in trustedChain.ChainStatus)
        {
            if(status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError || status.Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
            {
                //Acceptable Status, We want to know if it builds properly.
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: How is this better than opening an SSL URL on the desired server and handling any exceptions? You need to do this anyway . . .

Comment: @Terry, can you elaborate? I thought that was what is being done here prior which thereafter you are getting the certs from the connection to validate if you want to trust and continue with the connection. For this instance I had the issue where I had no control over the trusted CA files on the container so I had to ship the app with a certificate that I used to verify the thumbprint and chain.

Comment: The root certs need to be installed wherever the system keeps it's root certs. If you can't install the certs in the container, I'm not sure how anything is going to work. (it's also possible that I'm completely missing what you're trying to do)

Comment: That is definitely true, but in this case there is a Certificate Authority that was not installed on the container so I had to provide my own copy of root CA cert so I could verify connections. All of this was caused because these Docker Images do not contain custom configuration capabilities, at least on the level I am working at anyways.

Comment: Works like charm