# How to connect a Xamarin android application to Azure with a self signed certificate in C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

Dear Stackoverflow users,

I've linked an azure key vault self-signed certificate to my Azure web application, enabled *minimal* TLS v1.0 and set client certificate mode to `Required` to force SSL/TLS.

If I install the key vault pfx certificate on my windows machine and navigate to my url (ie: https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net) my browser prompt me to use my certificate otherwise I've got a 403 Frobidden error, and that's fine.

When I'm loading this pfx in my Xamarin android app, I've always got a `403 Frobidden error`.

Here is my code:

```csharp
    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() {
        SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
    })
    {
        //Add SSL certificat
        X509Certificate2 _privateCert = GetPrivateAPICertificate(); //get a self-signed pfx stored localy in the android filesystem
        if (_privateCert != null)
        {
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(_privateCert); 
            handler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
            
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
                {
                    return true; // <- when debugging return 2 Microsoft Azure certificate with subject *.azurewebsites.net but not the one I've added to my WebApp "TLS/SSL settings" blade.
                };
        }
    
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(url), Method = method })
            {
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                responseAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // <- Throw exception: "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)."
            }
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Edit: added `GetPrivateAPICertificate` function

```csharp
    private X509Certificate2 GetPrivateAPICertificate()
    {
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MyCoreAssembly)).Assembly;
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyCoreAssembly.mycert.pfx")))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                sr.BaseStream.CopyTo(ms);
                cert = new X509Certificate2(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
        return cert;
    }
```

---

## UPDATE

I've made some tests with postman, and if I add my pfx certificate in the settings of postman I can access the Azure API. This is not a certificate configuration problem in Azure.

I don't understand why the certificate is not send from Xamarin in my `HttpRequest` !

## UPDATE 2

I've also put the same exact code in a ASP.NET console application and it works. I think I have to add something to the my HTTP call in Xamarin...

Comment: Precision: the certificate was created with Azure Key Vault.

Comment: The industry 5 years ago decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 due to security issues.  In June this year Microsoft pushed a security update that disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and require TLS 1.2/1.3 to be used.  You need to upgrade to TLS 1.2/1.3.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the feedback. I've setup Azure to be the *minimal* TLS version to 1.0. I've tested with TLS 1.2 and i've got the same results: 403 forbidden (I've updated the code to use `SslProtocols.Tls12`).

Comment: Maybe the User Agent needs to be set in the header.  Some server will not accept all browsers.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Comment: I've added the UserAgent in the request but did not solve the problem: `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0");`.

Comment: Make sure the certificate raw data is intact,try to retrieving the certificate in Base 64 string format,like `cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(ms.ToArray()));`

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT thanks for the feedback. Their is no ctor of X509Certificate2 which takes a base64 encoded string. I'm reading the pfx file directlty from android embedded resource. I've checked the thumbprint after reading the pfx file and it correspond to the one generated by Azure KeyVault and the thumbprint displayed in the SSL/TLS Azure blade of the Web App. I'm 99% sure the pfx is correclty read and my `X509Certificate2 cert` variable is correctly initialized.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the fact that the certificate is self signed, and is not present in any "trusted store". I don't know how to tell Xamarin that it can trust my certificate or tell to the `HttpRequest` that it can be trusted...

Comment: Then the error on client would be that the certificate was not found  and would occur before the request was sent.  You are getting an error found on the server which means the request was sent.  Try validating certificate on client using following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137680/how-do-i-manually-validate-a-self-signed-certificate-in-c

Comment: I've tried the solution you linked without success. BTW, I've already implemented a "Certificate Validation Callback" in the linked code (`handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`) which always evaluate to **true**. Inside this callback the evaluated certificate subject is `CN=*.azurewebsite.net` and not the one I've created which is `CN=mywebapp.azurewebsites.net`.

Comment: I've made some tests with postman, and if I add my pfx certificate in the settings of postman I can access the Azure API. This is not a certificate configuration problem in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a way to achieve this.
The following post has the point:
[Xamarin Android - Call API using HttpClient with Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55707500/xamarin-android-call-api-using-httpclient-with-certificate)

By using `HttpWebRequest` instead of `HttpClient` I'm able to send my request with a certificate.

This is a regression since `HttpWebRequest` is less intuitive than the new `HttpClient` implementation, but that's the only solution I've found so far...

Comment: Glad to know that you resolve the issue by yourself, please accept it as answer, it will be beneficial for other communities who have similar issue.